# Flutter rest api authentication

Tags: flutter, api, rest, firebase-authentication

The accounts we added with createuser in Firebase authentication appear in the authentication section in firebase. Is it possible to do this with a rest service, not with authentication, and will it appear as if it was taken from authentication again?

Comment: "will it appear as if it was taken from authentication again?" Can you clarify what you mean by that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the [REST API for Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth), have a look at its reference documentation. Specifically, you may want to look at the docs for [creating an email/password user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-create-email-password) and [signing in with email/password](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth#section-sign-in-email-password).